# How much energy is released during the decay of 1 kg of neutronium?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, neutrons

i'm trying to find out what the decay energy is for neutronium. i'd like to find out if it would be a suitable fuel source for our civilization's needs (if we ignore the problem of extracting it from somewhere.)

Comment: Where would you extract it? You can't get close to a neutron star, because of the extreme tidal effect, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/631427/123208 And if it's a young neutron star, you also have an intense magnetic field and pulsar radiation to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

[Neutronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutronium) doesn't form as a stable bound state under normal conditions (i.e. pretty much anyplace outside the conditions found in a neutron star). If it did, it would be element number zero in the periodic table.

It doesn't form as a stable bound state because the residual strong force/nuclear binding force between two neutrons isn't quite sufficient to bind them, and because a free neutron is not stable. To only slightly oversimplify, [bound neutrons are stable only dynamically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron#Beta_decay_and_the_stability_of_the_nucleus), and only because their decay products cause protons to become neutrons at the same rate that neutrons decay to protons.

So, it would decay in a time frame that is too rapid to have practical use as a nuclear fuel, if it were formed in a laboratory (it does not exist in nature outside neutron stars).

> It is extremely radioactive; its only legitimate equivalent isotope,
> the free neutron, has a half-life of 10 minutes, which is
> approximately half that of the most stable known isotope of francium.
> Neutron matter decays quickly into hydrogen.

As a result of the Second Law of Thermodynamics, the formation energy will always exceed the decay energy in any actual physical system.

Furthermore, since it does not exist as a stable bound state, it would not be a useful way to store energy as a substitute for a battery.

Also, since it is electromagnetically neutral, even if you tried to "ionize it" since it has no electron shell, containing it in a compact fashion would be challenging. You couldn't use a magnetic cage to do so, and if you made enough of it, it would behave chemically as a non-reactive noble gas.

So, neutronium could not serve as a viable fuel source for any civilization.