Physical plausibility of space station between binary black holes
In science fiction you'll sometimes see a space station (or ancient alien relic, or something like that) dramatically suspended between two black holes (probably stellar-mass, but of course the masses aren't specifically addressed), which are generally separated by only a few times their radius. Obviously with Newtonian gravity there'd be a metastable point there, where something could remain with some amount of active station-keeping (assuming it can survive the tidal forces, radiation, etc.), but Newtonian gravity surely isn't a great approximation under the circumstances. Taking into account GR, would there still exist a metastable point under such circumstances where something could be kept for a long time (in general, or at least in a significant variety of cases)?
I can think of two differences between Newtonian gravity and GR that seem like they might be problematic, but I don't know enough to quantify their effect:

Eventually "between the black holes" will cease to be a place since the black holes will spiral in and merge due to gravity waves. I have been unable to find out any quantification of how long it takes black holes to go from several-radii separation to merging, so I'm not sure whether it's too short for it to make sense to build a space station there.
Realistically the black holes will be spinning, so there will be frame-dragging effects. I'm not sure if this will shift where the metastable point is or eliminate them entirely, and I'm not sure whether the answer to that depends on how close the black hole's rotational axes are to being aligned with each other and with the axis of the orbit.


An orbit around a stellar mass BH needs to be a large multiple of the Schwarzschild radius, otherwise the satellite gets spaghettified. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/631427/123208

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity#Gravitational_radiation has equations for the loss of energy & angular momentum, and reduction in orbital period, due to gravitational radiation.

As noted above, whether or not there is a metastable point between the black holes is not really relevant; even if there is, tidal forces will destroy any macroscopic object there. Even if your space station is made from super-strong unobtanium, its inhabitants aren't.

Frame dragging makes things move in the direction of the horizon movement. Therefore a metastable point would exist only if the black holes rotate in exactly the opposite directions and with the same speed (assuming equal masses).

You correctly identified that one of the problems with this scenario is that a configuration of two black holes separated by just a few Schwarzschild radii is not going to be very long lived.
For example, GW151226 (the second observed black hole merger) was separated by about 17 Schwarzschild radii when it entered the LIGO sensitivity band. It merged 1 second latter after just 55 orbits.
This would be a bit longer for heavier black holes, however even for the heaviest supermassive black holes with billions of solar masses we are talking only hundreds to thousands of years for a similar configuration.
